# How to handle multiple threads for laravel jobs?

Tags: multithreading, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-queue

I am working on a laravel project which involves the customers of the application to import data into the application through various other APIs.

I am thinking of making jobs for each kind of data that needs to imported. But, that would mean that many customers will be raising jobs that need to be worked by queue workers which means that if a customer has raised a job to import one job which is importing a certain kind of data, if another customer also raised a job to import the same kind of data, he would have to wait for the first customer's job to complete and then the second customer's job would be started to work by the queue working. But then we cannot have 100 customers waiting for each other.

So what would be a viable solution for this kind of imports? Should I put the jobs on hashed queues and then call those queues? Or is there a better way to handle this. Has anyone ever worked with such an application where data was being imported from various APIs by customers asynchronously. And how to handle it best.

Answer (score 0):

Your pointing in right direction. You need a queue worker such as Laravel's - but you need to choose the async driver. You can use the build-in drivers or try to install your own queue server like *RabbitMQ*. Here is a nice package with *RabbitMQ* driver for Laravel 5:

https://github.com/vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq

This will makes all your customers request will get into the async queue the separate threads for each one. These queues systems works very efficient and we can say that is a kind of   async PHP. For be more async inside PHP code you can use [Guzzle HTTP](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) package which provides Async Request (and full service from within the PHP code/server side of the application).